# TableView Determine Third Cell From Top

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, cell, nsindexpath

I constantly am trying to determine the third cell from the top of my table view. Basically, what that means is, the third cell from the top will always look different from all the others (i.e. the text color will change etc.).
I figured since the cells are reused, I would always be able to access the third cell like this:

```
if (indexPath.row == 2) {
    
    }
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be working like that. When I go ahead and print the `indexPath.row` the numbers continue to increase all the way from 0 to 12... Now this is understandable since it is that cells `row`, but how may I go about accessing the third row always from the top. Here is the original approach I took:

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    
        let indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows![0]
            
        if (indexPath.row == 2) {
          // Print or whatever
    
            }
        } 
    }
```

So how can I go about accessing the third row always from the top of the `tableView`?

Thank you!

Comment: You mean every 3,6,9 like that or 3rd from top like 5th is on top and then 7th will be third, So which one logic do you want?

Comment: @DharmbirSingh The second explanation. So basically lets say cell 5 is on top, cell 7 would be the one being edited. If the user then scrolled one more cell down, so cell 6 is on top, now cell 8 will change. Does that make sense? Thank you!

Comment: Please have a look on my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example project. I tried running it in the simulator and it seems to work fine.

Here is a screenshot of XCode so you can see Main.Storyboard.

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Video Walkthrough created with licecap]

Also here is a copy of the code in ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var indexOfThirdVisible: Int!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .BlackTranslucent
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows![0]
    indexOfThirdVisible = indexPath.row + 2
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: indexOfThirdVisible, inSection: indexPath.section)) as! TableViewCell
    cell.label.textColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

    let cellAbove = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: indexOfThirdVisible - 1, inSection: indexPath.section)) as! TableViewCell
    let cellBelow = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: indexOfThirdVisible + 1, inSection: indexPath.section)) as! TableViewCell
    cellAbove.label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    cellBelow.label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 100
}
// heightForRowAtIndexPath
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}
// configure cell
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")!
    return cell
}
}
```

Here is TableViewCell.swift:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Sorry if the indentation is messed up.
Have a good day and let me know if you need any more help!

Answer (score 1):

I just implemented only logic, you can customise it little bit according to you.

```
    func scrollViewDidEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    let indexPath : NSIndexPath = (tv.indexPathsForVisibleRows as! NSArray).objectAtIndex(0) as! NSIndexPath

    let thirdRow = indexPath.row + 2
    if thirdRow <= dataArr.count{// dataArr is your no of rows

        let thirdIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: thirdRow, inSection: 0)

        let cell = tv.cellForRowAtIndexPath(thirdIndexPath)
        // ---- here you can perform any task with third cell----

    }
}
```

And please let me know if anything is wrong